# Get orders total purchases amount for the day in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

For Woocommerce, I wrote code below, trying to get orders total purchases amount for today:

```
function order_total_woo_fahad(){

    // Get orders from people named John that were paid in the year 2016.
$orders = wc_get_orders( array(
    'date_paid' => '2018-07-03'
) );
$total_of_all=0;
for($i=0;$orders[i];$i++)
    $total_of_all= $orders[i]->get_total();
    return $total_of_all;
}
```

But it returns null.

What I am doing wrong? How can I get orders total purchases amount for the day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best and effective way to get that is to use the following very light SQL query, that will get the sum of all order totals in the last 24 hours for "processing" and "completed" orders statuses:

```
function get_daily_purchases_total(){
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND p.post_status IN ('wc-processing','wc-completed')
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (86400))
        AND pm.meta_key = '_order_total'
    " );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE Example** - Display the daily total purchased formatted amount:

```
<?php echo '<p>Total purchased of the day: ' . strip_tags( wc_price(get_daily_purchases_total() ) ) . '</p>'; ?>
```

---

If you want to get instead the total **based on the "today" date**, you will replace in the code this line:

```
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (86400))
```

by this line:

```
AND DATE(p.post_date) >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: Hi Loic. It does return the order total but it returns it with html, example :
`<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">AED</span> 140.00</span>
`

Comment: Do you have any idea how to limit this query only for purchased made by the current user who is login in to his/her account?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec is it possible to get total sales on specific category?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$date_from = '2015-11-20';
$date_to = '2015-12-20';
$post_status = implode("','", array('wc-processing', 'wc-completed') );

$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts 
            WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
            AND post_status IN ('{$post_status}')
            AND post_date BETWEEN '{$date_from}  00:00:00' AND '{$date_to} 23:59:59'
        ");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
?>
```