# gmdate and timezones + woo commerce api

Tags: date, woocommerce

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York);
$after_date = gmdate('c', strtotime('-1 hour));

//Make API call to get orders AFTER 1 hour ago
$params = array('after' => $after_date);
$orders_since_last_sync = $Woo_orders->get_orders($params);
```

The problem is I don't know the timezone of the woo commerce server. Is gmdate going to be timezone agnostic? Woo Commerce `after` parameter is described as `Limit response to resources published after a given ISO8601 compliant date.`

What is the best way to pull in orders if the woo commerce server timezone and my timezone are different. What is gmdate going to be? What is the difference between the oldest and newest timezone?

The end goal is to get orders placed since the last hour no matter what the timezone is on the server where this code runs and the timezone of the woo commerce server.

Comment: The time zone used by woocommerce, is the one that is set in Wordpress general settings, for your web site. Now if you use PHP functions related to date and time, it will use the hosting server time zone. In Wordpress and Woocommerce, there is a lot of dedicated date and time functions that will take in account the Wordpress defined time zone.

Comment: But if the wordpress timezone is unknown what is the best way to make get sales since the last hour?

Comment: May be have a look to this recent threads (that can help you): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51664796/3730754 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51165375/3730754 …