# Sql query to exclude meta_value where meta_key = x on SUM for WooCommerce

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

Using *[Get orders total purchases amount for the day in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152861/get-orders-total-purchases-amount-for-the-day-in-woocommerce/51165375#51165375)* answer code, returns the total value of woocommerce orders which works fine, but the problem is if I want to exclude all the orders where `_billing_first_name` key has not **abc** value, like in this code attempt:

```
global $wpdb;

return $wpdb->get_var( "
    SELECT DISTINCT SUM(pm.meta_value)
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
    AND p.post_status IN ('wc-processing','wc-completed')
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (86400))
    AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_order_total'
    AND NOT (pm.meta_value = 'abc')
" );
```

I have tried a number of ways with no luck, any help is appreciated

Comment: There is a smoother light way than in your answer, see below.

Comment: Just to observe that it's fantastically unlikely (though not impossible) that you would intentionally use the DISTINCT modifier in conjunction with an aggregate function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use 2 INNER JOIN for the same table with a different reference as following *(to avoid a double query like in your answer)*:

```php
global $wpdb;

return $wpdb->get_var( "
    SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value)
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.post_id
    WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
    AND p.post_status IN ('wc-processing','wc-completed')
    AND pm.meta_key = '_order_total'
    AND pm2.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' 
    AND pm2.meta_value != 'abc'
" );
```

Tested and works smoother.

Comment: `DISTINCT`, `LIKE 'shop_order'`, `LIKE '_order_total'`, no alias for the selected column... While they might not go to the heart of the question, these strike me as careless (unless you think that this is a case sensitive collation), don't you think?

Comment: @Strawberry Yes you are also right for both `LIKE`… What do you mean when you say *"no alias for the selected column"*, I am not so skilled. I am just good enough with WooCommerce.

Comment: Well, when you select some data, it's nice to be able to reference that data elsewhere in code. `SUM(pm.meta_value)` is a cumbersome thing to attempt to reference (by association), so it's tempting to provide an alias, `AS total`, for instance.

Comment: @Strawberry Ok I get it, but not really useful in here. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone looking into this the fix i made is:

```php
global $wpdb;

return $wpdb->get_var( "
    SELECT DISTINCT SUM(pm.meta_value)
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
    AND p.post_status IN ('wc-processing','wc-completed')
    AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_order_total'
    AND pm.post_id not in(SELECT post_id from wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_billing_first_name' AND meta_value ='abc' )
" );
```